# android connect to PC's localhost when debugger on mobile device

Tags: android

I want to debug my android application, I connect the android device to my PC using the USB cable. In my application there is a button to connect with localhost, ip for localhost is `10.0.2.2` and the port is `8080`, I have read that when debugging on mobile, the ip `10.0.2.2` is the localhost for android device and not for my PC, so what changes should I make to the ip instead of `10.0.2.2`? or do I have to make another change?
In this case my android device is `sony ericsson xperia arc s`.

Comment: which server u r using??.. like wamp or xampp

Comment: tomcat java on eclipse, and xampp for database

Comment: You mean `mysql` for database?

Comment: Have you tried with System's Static IP Address?

Comment: @user370305 i don't know what is static ip, but i read that i can set the ip on eclipse to some numbers and put that numbers on code instead of `10.0.2.2` , is that right?

Comment: System's IP is something like, 192.168.X.X you can find it using command **ipconfig**

Comment: @user370305 i found this `IPv4 Address 192.168.1.101` , now have i to put that ip instead of `10.0.2.2` or what ?

Comment: Put 192.168.1.101 instead of 10.0.2.2 and let me know what happen..

Comment: it works finally , really big thank you, i accept your answer, really thaaaaaank you man

Comment: @user370305 by replacing `10.0.2.2` with my system's ip address i'll be able to connect my device with xampp ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As **10.0.2.2** is your system (pc)'s local host address (from emulator only). Actually android doesn't recognized **localhost** in url. so **10.0.2.2** is for that meant. Also for android device loopback address is **127.0.0.1**.

Your url with 10.0.2.2 is correct. Also you can use **Static IP** of your system.

Just check for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

in your application's manifest file.

**EDIT:**

Here you are using port 8080 so, try with **adb command** on your host machine.

```
adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

Also please elaborate on this line **"i want to debugger my application on my mobile"**.

**Note:**

If you are going to test on real device use your **Network IP** of system (PC).

Comment: i already set that permission, so y i can't access my localhost from mobile ?

Comment: if am always afraid of cmd so i will ask : if i did this commad `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080` can i keeping working on emulator? and is xampp will still working, and is there anything i will lose?

Comment: When you are communicating with USB port, by adb forward command you can open particular port for communication with your app and your host machine (server-client). You can't lose anything.

Comment: Using adb forward - Forwards socket connections from a specified local port to a specified remote port on the emulator/device instance.

Comment: now i changed the `10.0.2.2` to `127.0.0.1` , but still doesn't work, i will run the command and till you what happend, thank you for the nice answer

Comment: Don't change 10.0.2.2.And 127.0.01 is for loopback address of emulator. only use 10.0.2.2 for local host.

Comment: i make that command , and still `10.0.2.2` but the mobile doesn't connect to the server

Comment: This answer should not have been accepted as it neither solves nor identifies the actual problem.  The fundamental problem is that the 10.0.2.2 address is only available to *emulators* and not to physical devices.

Comment: I am using port `8000` so should i use abd ?

Comment: my friends, try `adb reverse tcp:<PORT> tcp:<PORT>`

Answer (score 29):

Google has added support in Chrome 29 and higher to use **reverse port forwarding** to access a website hosted on your local development machine **through the USB cable** on Chrome for Android. Setup instructions can be found at the following URL:

- [Android Remote Debugging - Reverse Port Forwarding](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging?hl=de#port-forwarding)
- [Tools for Web Developers - Access Local Servers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server)

As of desktop Chrome 30 Reverse Port Forwarding is no longer an experimental feature in Chrome. It can be accessed by typing `about:inspect` in the address bar of your PC, and by clicking the "Enable port forwarding" check box and clicking the "Configure port forwarding" button located to the top right of the window.

Once that is done, connect your mobile device via USB. Open Chrome on your mobile device to `localhost:8000` (or whichever port you have configured on your local server).

The Reverse Port Forwarding functionality will make sure that your Android device now sees your PC's `localhost`.

Comment: Chrome has made this very easy now - no more configuration of your local server, it all gets done automatically. It also gets around the problem of having to configure your firewall to allow external connections, which many of the other techniques require.

Comment: The correct answer should be changed to be this one.

Comment: I think this should actually link to https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server

Comment: This also says nothing about configuring the firewall on the dev machine.

Comment: I'm trying this right now and the port connection is timing out when I'm making an API request to the port 8080.

Answer (score 5):

For that you need to make some changes in your xampp server... Assign 1 static IP address to your system and then you need to put your xampp server in online mode. after that you can use that ip address in your android application instead of 10.0.2.2. Works fine for me as i am using my localhost with my android application.

Comment: my server is tomcat , and to deal with database `mysql` i am using xampp, if that xampp for database is what you mean by xampp server, tell me please how can i assign static ip to system , and how can i put xampp server in online mode, but i told you that xampp just for database , myserver is java tomcat on eclipse

Comment: Jus check the ip address of your system. Since you are using tomcat server then no need to put xampp in online mode, but it should be in running mode. you can use your system ip plus your tomcat port number to access your web service file. eg if ur system ip address is 192.111.1.111 and ur tomcat port number is 8080(by default) then u need to use 192.111.1.111:8080 instead of 10.0.2.2...

Answer (score 3):

You can share your Mac's Internet connection over Wi-Fi.  Then your Android app can connect to a Servlet running on the Mac with HTTP over Wi-Fi. The steps are:

1. Run System Preference on Mac
2. Goto "Sharing" tab
3. Turn on "Internet Sharing"
4. Select "Ethernet" in the "Share your connection from" combo
5. Select "Wi-Fi" in the "To Computers Using" list box
6. Use "Wi-Fi Options..." button to configure Wi-Fi security. Now your Mac is a Wi-Fi server, and it is sharing its Ethernet Internet connection.
7. Configure your Android device's Wi-Fi to connect to your Mac (in Settings command)
8. On your Mac, goto the Network tab in System Preferences, and select Wi-Fi in list to find out the IP address of your Mac on the Wi-Fi network (for me it was 169.254.66.223)
9. In your Android App you can now connect to the Servlet in your Mac with "http://169.254.66.223:8080/YourServer/YourServlet"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options

The first one  is using 10.0.2.3 when you use your real android device.it works for me.

Your Second opt  is creating  hotspot from your pc and connect your android device to the hotspot.

Find the ip address  using cmd type "ipconfig"  replace localhost with the  ip address.

Thanks.

Comment: 10.0.2.3 does not exist