# Why i'm getting timeout when trying to connect from my android device to the web server on my pc?

Tags: java, c#, android, android-studio, networking

The web server on the pc is in c#
In the form1 constructor:

```
var ws = new WebServer(
    request => Task.Run(() => SendResponseAsync(request)),
    "http://+:8098/");
    ws.Run();
```

This two methods

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
        }

        public void Send(string ipaddress)
        {
            UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 15000);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ipaddress);
            client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, ip);
            client.Close();
        }
```

Then in timer tick event interval set to 1000ms

```
int countsends = 0;
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (countsends == 10)
            {
                Send(localipadd);
                countsends = 0;
            }
            countsends += 1;
        }
```

And the WebServer class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Automatic_Record
{
    class WebServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, Task<string>> _responderMethod;

        public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, Task<string>> method)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
                    throw new NotSupportedException(
                        "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

                // URI prefixes are required, for example 
                // "http://localhost:8080/index/".
                if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
                    throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

                // A responder method is required
                if (method == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("method");

                foreach (string s in prefixes)
                    _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

                _responderMethod = method;
                _listener.Start();
            }
            catch(AccessViolationException err)
            {
                string error = err.StackTrace;
            }
        }
}
```

On the pc side the c# i'm not getting any errors or exceptions and using break point i can see the pc ip on the network on the router on the method Send on variable ipaddress it's value is 10.0.0.1 i also logged in to my router settings and i saw that the pc is on 10.0.0.1

Now the java side in the android-studio where i'm trying to get the pc ip and to connect to it:

At the top of mainactivity: ( I tried before port 8098 but it didn't work so i tried 15000 but also didn't work still getting timeout message )

```
private String[] ipaddresses = new String[]{
            "http://10.0.0.1:15000/?cmd=nothing"
            };
```

Then a button click method calling from onCreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnButton();
        currentActivity = this;
        initTTS();
    }
```

The addListenerOnButton

```
public void addListenerOnButton()
    {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connecttoserverbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusTextView);

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)

                        {
                            counter = i;
                            try
                            {
                                response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                String err = e.toString();
                            }

                            if (response!=null)
                            {


                                try
                                {
                                    final String a = new String(response, "UTF-8");




                                    text.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            text.setText(a + " Oמ " + ipaddresses[counter]);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    iptouse = ipaddresses[i].substring(0,ipaddresses[i].lastIndexOf("=")+1);
                                    connectedtoipsuccess = true;
                                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("encoding exception");
                                }

                                Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("test1");
                                break;

                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }





                        }
                        counter = 0;
                        if (response == null)
                        {
                            text.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    text.setText("Connection Failed");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

    }
```

And last the Get method

```
private byte[] Get(String urlIn)
    {
        URL url = null;
        String urlStr = urlIn;
        if (urlIn!=null)
            urlStr=urlIn;

        try
        {
            url = new URL(urlStr);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            byte[] buf=new byte[10*1024];
            int szRead = in.read(buf);
            byte[] bufOut;

            if (szRead==10*1024)
            {
                throw new AndroidRuntimeException("the returned data is bigger than 10*1024.. we don't handle it..");
            }
            else
            {
                bufOut = Arrays.copyOf(buf, szRead);
            }
            return bufOut;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (urlConnection!=null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

My android device is also connected to the same network on the router with wifi i checked on the router settings and i see my device.

I used a break point on the android-studio side inside the Get method.
It's getting to the line:

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

Then i click continue and that's it here it's hanging and instead keep going to the next line `byte[] buf=new byte[10*1024];` after about 30 seconds it's jumping to:  `e.printStackTrace();`

android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
failed to connect to /10.0.0.1 (port 15000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

I can't see any exceptions in the logcat.

Comment: Erhm... youre listening on port 8098 but trying to connect to port 15000? also, does your computer have the ip 10.0.0.1? to check the ip don't go to the router, open cmd and write "ipconfig /all"

Comment: Another hint, if there's an exception on your server you will swallow it silently, HttpListener needs administrator permissions unless you grant the user acces to it, so maybe your server is not working at all? try to connect from a browser on your machine

Comment: If i try with the browser with chrome: http://10.0.0.1:8098/?cmd=nothing then i'm getting message on chrome: Connection Success. So it's working but for some reason when trying to connect from the device it's getting time out. And i tried also from the device to connect with  http://10.0.0.1:8098/?cmd=nothing and still time out.

Comment: Then what you don't have is a route to your computer from the android device. Check this post, the second solution should be the right one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328554/android-connect-to-pcs-localhost-when-debugger-on-mobile-device

Comment: The solution was by adding and allowing the program/port in the windows firewall. Now it's working. Thank you.