# Connect android device locally by using a web service

Tags: android, android-studio, yii, xampp

I am newbie to native android development. I have created a `DB` in `phpmyadmin` using `xampp` server. Then i created a  `REST webservice` using `Yii`. I tested the web service on `ARC` and it's working fine. Now i want to test it on my device. So i searched many articles and found a answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328581/6854117)). But it doesn't helped me out. Below is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String URLGET = "http://192.168.8.85:8000/app/web/users/";
String result = "";
TextView getData;
EditText userInput;
public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    getData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getData);
    userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterId);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Submit);


    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String reqURL = URLGET;

            new RestOperation().execute(reqURL);
            //callWebService(query);
        }
    });

}

public class RestOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


    final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String content;
    String error;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    String data = "";

   // TextView getData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getData);
   // EditText userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterId);


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        data = "data=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(userInput.getText()));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);


            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.flush();

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));


            }

            content = sb.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            error = " Exception: " + e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = " IOException: " + e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(br != null)
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if (error != null) {
            getData.setText("Error" + error);
        } else {
            getData.setText(content);


        }
    }
}}
```

The above `ip` address is my wireless address. Firstly i was testing it on emulator using `localhost` but on searching i found that i should use `10.0.2.2`. So i use it and it still doesn't works. I gives me the a `warning` in `logcat` as shown below

[image][image]

I must be missing some thing that i don't know. I am stuck to it from almost 2-3 days and really don't know what to do.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Your device and computer should be in the same network. Use IP Address of that network and turn off the firewall.

Comment: Ok let me do it and i'll tell you

Comment: I did what you said i run the app and this error is shown `java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.8.85 (port 8000): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)`

Comment: Hit the URL in the browser check if it's working.

Comment: No it's not, it's only working with `localhost`

Comment: I am using wireless internet so in `cmd` under `Wireless LAN adapter WiFi` the `IPv4 Address` is my `Network Ip` right ?

Comment: What is the ip address of your android device, is it 192.168.8.x ?

Comment: @wrkwrk yes it's `192.168.8.85`

Comment: Make sure your web server is listening on 0.0.0.0:8000, and the phone is under the same network (using the same wifi). If the server is listening on 127.0.0.1:8000, it can only be accessed by localhost(127.0.0.1).

Comment: My phone and my system are under same network. I have already tried to connect it with the `localhost` but i am getting same error again again though it's working on my web browser.

Comment: I am using wireless internet so in cmd under Wireless LAN adapter WiFi the IPv4 Address is my Network Ip right ? **Yes. Use it.**

Comment: @mdg5435 yes i am using it but still unable to connect

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Wifi Hotspot of your Android phone/router and connect your Laptop to your phone.

Start your server at localhost (I am using wamp server)

Now open command prompt and enter **ipconfig** command you will get following things

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::80bc:e378:19ab:e448%11
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : **192.168.43.76**
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
```

Copy this **192.168.43.76**  in your mobile browser.

**Note : Please set your network as "Home Network".** Setting Home Network means allowing your PC to share stuff with other devices on the same network.
 If your using Windows 10 go to WiFi > Network properties of current network > Make this PC Discoverable.

Original Answer : [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device/15864222#15864222)

Comment: What do you mean `Turn on Wifi Hotspot of your Android phone/router` ?
Do i have to turn on the `Wifi` or `Wifi Hotspot` these both are different i guess

Comment: This answer is for reference. You can use `WiFi Hotspot of your android device` or `WiFi`. Just, make sure your device and computer are in the same network, XAMPP/WAPP is running, Firewall is turned off.

Comment: Ok i can see the result in web browser, but i want to access my application as i have posted screen shots.

Comment: Check now in the device also.

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.8.65:8000/app/web/users/` :(